# Constraints to replace frame for UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, constraints, frame, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to replace a set frame with constrains for a UIButton but my code keeps crashing, what am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)CreateButton {
self.Button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
//self.Button.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100);
[self.Button addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:MyScrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.myButton
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:2.0
                                                           constant:30]];
[self.myButton addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:MyScrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.myButton
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:3.0
                                                           constant:50]];
[self.myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Press Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[MyScrollView addSubview:self.myButton];
```

Comment: *"Crashing"*, hmm? We probably could be of more help if you show us the error message **and** tell us the **exact** line of your code that is causing the crash.

Comment: assuming you want to setup constraints for a single button, at least you have two different in the code above (self.Button and self.myButton)

Comment: and try to stick obj-C naming conventions for the sake of Universe simplicity. That will help you to avoid such issues in the future https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html

Comment: Also you need to add your UIButton to your scrollView before adding your constraints

Comment: And, you've got to write :   `self.myButton.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` before adding constraints.

Comment: And, I agree with @slxl I assume you wanted to write `self.myButton` instead of `self.Button` at the beginning of your code

Answer (score 0):

You should add the constraint to MyScrollView.

Comment: that shouldn't lead to a crash.

Comment: From the documentation of UIView:addConstraint: "The constraint must involve only views that are within scope of the receiving view. Specifically, any views involved must be either the receiving view itself, or a subview of the receiving view. Constraints that are added to a view are said to be held by that view. The coordinate system used when evaluating the constraint is the coordinate system of the view that holds the constraint."